# Could SEO be negatively impacted if an anchor tag has been used without an href attribute in several places?

Tags: seo, html, ranking, anchor

I have a site where anchor tags are used without any `href` attribute and the site's ranking is not good. Is it possible that there's a negative impact on SEO if anchor tags have been used without an `href` attribute in several different places in a page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine. Anchor tags aren't always used with href attributes anyway. You can use the name attribute, which is used when linking to different parts of the page.

```
<a name="sectionName">Page Section</a>
```

Comment: The `name=` attribute is obsolete.  `id="sectionName"` would be a more appropriate and useful example.